# BiometricPrompt class not available in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-9.0-pie

I've switched to the Xamarin SDK beta channel, and they say they have Android 9.0 support there, however after switching / downloading / installing the latest SDK's and targeting Android 9.0 in my Android project, I still am not seeing the BiometricPrompt class available for consumption. I need to leverage this for facial recognition on login in my app, and to replace the FingerprintManager class (at least for Android 9 devices.)

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Which actual version of `Xamarin.Android` is installed? (And if you use the full namespace does it work? (Maybe an intelisense fail?) `Android.Hardware.Biometrics.BiometricPrompt`

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm using Xamarin.Android Version: 9.1.0.38. When I try the full namespace I get: Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Biometrics' does not exist in the namespace 'Android.Hardware' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) (com.rpr.mobile.droid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **compile** target must be set to Android 9.0 (Pie) to gain access to the API Level 28 SDK:

[image]

Then the **runtime** target needs to be set to Android 9.0 API level 28 (or "auto" which would be the **compile** target of 28). From there you can do your API level checks at runtime to determine which APIs to call.

[image]